# Passar o texto em vez do id na dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Queria passar a o texto da dropdown para o controlador(Post) em vez do id, não sei como posso fazer isso.

Controlador:

```
  ViewBag.AnoCatequeseID = new SelectList(db.AnoCatequese, "AnoCatequeseID", "Ano");
```

View:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.grupo.AnoCatequese, (SelectList)ViewBag.AnoCatequeseID, "--Escolha um ano de Catequese--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi simplista mas funcionou:

```
ViewBag.AnoCatequeseID = new SelectList(db.AnoCatequese, "Ano", "Ano");
```

Answer (score 0):

Usando outra construção de `@Html.DropDownListFor`:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.grupo.AnoCatequeseID, 
    ((IEnumerable<AnoCatequese>)ViewBag.AnoCatequeseID).Select(ac =>
        new SelectListItem {
            Text = ac.Ano,
            Value = ac.AnoCatequeseID,
            Selected = (Model.grupo != null) && (Model.grupo.AnoCatequeseID == ac.AnoCatequeseID)
        }), 
    "--Escolha um ano de Catequese--", 
    htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" }
)
```

Comment: Não estou a perceber qual o argumento dentro do '(IEnumerable<????>)', está a dar erro.

Comment: Acrescente `@using SeuSistema.Models` no topo da *View*.

Comment: AnoCatequese é uma class auxiliar sem qualquer tipo de ligação no meu modelo, e que vai preencher um campo do tipo string no meu modelo grupo. em que estou a utilizar uma Viewmodel. `@model WebAppCatechesis2.ViewModels.GrupoViewModel`. Continua a dizer que não tenho nenhuma referencia no IEnumerable

Comment: `db.AnoCatequese` devolve qual *Model*?

Comment: model `AnoCatequese`.

Comment: Então é isso mesmo. `AnoCatequese` não é uma classe auxiliar.

Comment: É uma tabela auxiliar não tenho nenhuma ligação a ela.